# Is a Content Security Policy and a sandboxed iframe sufficient for allowing user-submitted html with inline scripts?

Tags: javascript, html, content-security-policy

I'm trying to create a website where users can submit HTML with inline scripts, styles, etc. From my testing, using a Content Security Policy and a sandboxed iframe seems to block most malicious actions such as sending / receiving data from external sources.

I'm using `srcdoc` instead of `src` as `src` doesn't seem to inherit the CSP.

My current HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"   content="default-src 'none'; style-src 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'unsafe-inline'">
        <meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none'; style-src 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'unsafe-inline'">
        <meta http-equiv="X-WebKit-CSP"              content="default-src 'none'; style-src 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'unsafe-inline'">
        
    </head>
    <style>
        iframe {
            width: 100%;
            height: 95vh;
        }
    </style>
    <iframe srcdoc="$$$" sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-scripts">
        <p>Your browser does not support iframes</p>
    </iframe>
</html>
```

Where `$$$` is replaced by the injected HTML with all double quotes replaced by `&quot;`.

Is this secure enough for user-generated content and can/should I do anything to protect the user's local files?

Comment: If you are 100% sure that you have covered all the possible things that canbe done in javascript /web-assembly and so on : possibly. If you are saving the uploaded html as a file and then including it, you also have to make sure that any supported server side scripting is also  blocked (a CSP will not prevent a PHP script from contacting a remote server...). personally I would provide a subset of allowed tags and include them in a `<div>` rather than allow a whole html file to be uploaded.

Comment: Also remember that if the user generated code runs on the same domain/subdomain as your server, other code may be included from your domain that may be used as if it is your own. a separate subdomain for the user-generated content may alleviate this.

Comment: Yes.. Any website you go to can execute any code it wishes, but as your aware generally speaking that's not a concern.  What is a concern is allowing untrusted code access using the same origin.  Why?  Because it then has access to your cookies / localeStorage etc, I don't think I need to explain why that's bad.  So as a default a sandboxed iFrame should be all you need..

Comment: @JoSSte Could you elaborate on how you could implement the subset of tags idea? Would this require server-side processing to guarantee that only the allowed tags are used? I need scripting to be enabled and I believe that JavaScript could bypass any sort of primitive tag filter. No server-side scripting will be used to serve this page and while there will be a subdomain for user content, the CSP blocks any non-inline scripts and remote content should have the same permissions as inline content.

Comment: @Keith Will this be sufficient for preventing other activities such as sending user data to a remote sever? Is there a way for the iframe to override the parent's CSP?

Comment: @Bob Any client-side-only filtering is easily bypassible. If you want to continue with this, the different sub-domain is a must have. And try some fuzz testing with the "I am an attacker" hat on - see what you can access. read up on XSS and filter bypassing.

Comment: It's treated like a separate origin, so your CSP should still work.  There is an option to turn that off, but the default is on and will fail all CSP requests.

Comment: @Bob an `<img src="https://my-evil-server.com/somemaliciousscript.php?getimage=true">` would be remote and i doubt that the csp would block that. It may be that js requests are blocked - but I'd recommend trying it out. remember that the browser is userland - not controlled by you. You may secure your servers from malicious actors, but the users PC would potentially be vulnerable

Comment: "*HTML with all quotes replaced with double quotes*" - yeah don't do that. Use proper entity escapes. Not sure what problems you expect from `&quot;`

Comment: My bad, I missed the `;` when inserting `&quot;` and just assumed that it was buggy as it would only sometimes work.